# How to add multiple products to cart programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, addtocart

This is the code snippet that I am using

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quote = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1058);
$params = array (
    'qty' => 1
);
$quote->addProduct($_product, $params);
$quote->save();

$quote = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$product = null;

$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1059);
$params = array (
    'qty' => 3
);
$quote->addProduct($_product, $params);

$quote->save();
```

The code seems fine but it updates the quantity of 1st product and results into 4 quantities of first product added to cart.

Please help.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but try with `$objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')` instead of `$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')`

Comment: In this case... I added it as an answer with some extra explanations about why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments:
You should use

```
$objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
```

instead of

```
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
```

This happens because `get` instantiates a class as a singleton. `create` always gets you a new instance.
In the code you have, you will get the same instance of the product the second time you try to instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, without using **Object Manager**

```
$_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(1059);
```

Instead of

```
$_product = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1059);
```

So, you need to inject **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory** in the constructor of class where you are using that snippet